# ASP.NET MVC SiteMap with Ninject controller factory error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, sitemap, ninject

I am trying to use the ASP.NET MVC Codeplex Sitemap project with Custom Dynamic Node provider. This is my node provider code. It uses some repository to access the DB. I actually don't use DI in this class but the application inherits NinjectHttpApplication and the Sitemap has problems acquiring controller.

```
public class ContentPageDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    private IRepository _repository;

    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
    {
        // Build value 
        var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();

        // Create a node for each content page
        _repository = new XmlDefaultRepository(ContentType.Page);
        foreach(var page in _repository.GetInstances())
        {
            DynamicNode node = new DynamicNode();
            node.Title = page.Title;
            node.ParentKey = "Default";
            node.RouteValues.Add("slug", page.Slug);
            returnValue.Add(node);
        }

        // Return 
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Then in Site.Master I try to render the breadcrumbs like this:

```
<%=Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() %>
```

My default route that starts when running the site is Page/Display/{slug} and for slug I use the "Default", here is the global.asax.cs part

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultPage", RouteType.Regular,
            "",
            new { controller = "Page", action = "Display", slug = "Default" }, null
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "PageBySlug", RouteType.Regular,
            "{slug}",
            new { controller = "Page", action = "Display", slug = "Default" }, null
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", RouteType.Regular,
            "{controller}/{action}/{slug}",
            new { controller = "Page", action = "Display", slug = "Default" }, null
            );
```

The problem I have is that when Custom Site Node Provider is in place I get this error at runtime:

Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: controllerName

This is the stack trace (maybe it will help someone identify what is going on). As far as I can tell it goes to Ninject for controller but does not get one.

> [ArgumentException: Value cannot be
>   null or empty. Parameter name:
>   controllerName]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)
>   +167    Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)
>   +151    MvcSiteMapProvider.AuthorizeAttributeAclModule.IsAccessibleToUser(IControllerTypeResolver
>   controllerTypeResolver,
>   DefaultSiteMapProvider provider,
>   HttpContext context, SiteMapNode node)
>   +533    MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule.IsAccessibleToUser(IControllerTypeResolver
>   controllerTypeResolver,
>   DefaultSiteMapProvider provider,
>   HttpContext context, SiteMapNode node)
>   +149    MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider.IsAccessibleToUser(HttpContext
>   context, SiteMapNode node) +24
>   System.Web.SiteMapNode.IsAccessibleToUser(HttpContext
>   context) +17
>   System.Web.SiteMapProvider.ReturnNodeIfAccessible(SiteMapNode
>   node) +42
>   System.Web.StaticSiteMapProvider.FindSiteMapNode(String
>   rawUrl) +176
>   MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider.FindSiteMapNode(HttpContext
>   context) +282
>   System.Web.SiteMapProvider.get_CurrentNode()
>   +56    MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper.SiteMapPath(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper
>   helper, String separator, String
>   separatorCssClass, String
>   linkCssClass, Boolean
>   currentNodeAsLink, Object
>   htmlAttributes) +81
>   MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper.SiteMapPath(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper
>   helper) +30
>   ASP.views_site_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) +499

Any help appreciated.

Also please note that without the custom node provider (just the static nodes in .sitemap file) everything works fine.

Comment: Won't your first route "" match anything and always be used?

Comment: no, empty url means the root..

Answer (score -1):

Just a thought, but do you need to add the controller and action values?

```
node.RouteValues.Add("controller", "Page");
node.RouteValues.Add("action", "Display");
```